# Grails GORM count function in a named query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm writing some named queries for my domain classes in Grails and I've hit a blocker.

Given the following domain class:

```
class Contributor {
    // evals is a collection of another domain class
    def evals

    static namedQueries = {
        hasNoEvals {
            // Something like this...
            evals.size() == 0
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with the syntax I need to select the Contributors who have no Evals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look in [`createCriteria` doc](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest//ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for "collection property" operations. In your case, it is `isEmpty`:

```
static namedQueries = {
    hasNoEvals {
        isEmpty('evals')
    }
}
```

For generic size restriction, it is `sizeEq`, `sizeLe` and so on.